# i want to call a java class from the worklight adapter

Tags: java, javascript, ibm-mobilefirst

i have followed this document module 5.5 in this url "http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#authentication"  or  ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v505/Module_05_5_-_Using_Java_in_Adapters.pdf

and did the same my code structure is

```
server/java                        folder name
com.worklight.custonmode           package name
loginfunction.java                 java file inside com.worklight.custonmode package
login                              java method in class loginfunction
```

and i have called from the worklight adapter as

```
function loginmodules(username, passwd) {   
    return {
        result : com.worklight.custonmode.loginfunction.login()
    };
}
```

when i am calling am getting the error like this as

```
 response [/apps/services/api/Light/common/query] success: /*-secure- {"responseID":"2","errors":["Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot call property login in object [JavaPackage com.worklight.custonmode.loginfunction]. It is not a function, it is \"object\".
```

(C%3A%5CUsers%5CADMIN%5CworkspaceM11%5CMobileClient%5Cadapters%5CAdapter/Adapter-impl.js#103)"],"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/

```
    worklight.js (line 1112)

    Procedure invocation error. Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot call property login in object [JavaPackage com.worklight.custonmode.loginfunction]. It is not a function, it is "object". (C%3A%5CUsers%5CADMIN%5CworkspaceM11%5CMobileClient%5Cadapters%5CAdapter/Adapter-impl.js#103)
```

my login function in loginfunction.java

```
  public class loginfunction {

public static void login() {
    //============== Code to adapt to your own configuration =============//
    String server = "https://ibm-f4acjqe8c6p:9443/dfd";     // Set the Public URI of your RRC server
    String JTS_Server = "https://ibm-f4acjqe8c6p:9443/jts"; //Set the public URI of your JTS server
    String login = "Admin";                                 // Set the user login 
    String password = "Admin";                              // Set the associated password
    //============== -------------------------------------- =============//

    String rootServices = server + "/rootservices";
    String catalogXPath = "/rdf:Description/oslc_we:rweServiceProviders/@rdf:resource";
    String serviceProviderTitleXPath = "//oslc:ServiceProvider/dcterms:title";

    System.out.println(">> Example03: Print out the content of the Service Providers catalog");
    System.out.println("    - Root Services URI: "+rootServices);
    System.out.println("    - Service Providers catalog XPath expression: "+catalogXPath);
    System.out.println("    - Service Provider title XPath expression: "+serviceProviderTitleXPath);
    System.out.println("    - Login: "+login);
    System.out.println("    - Password: "+password);

    // Setup the HttClient
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpUtils.setupLazySSLSupport(httpclient);

    // Setup the rootServices request
    HttpGet rootServiceDoc = new HttpGet(rootServices);
    rootServiceDoc.addHeader("Accept", "application/rdf+xml");
    rootServiceDoc.addHeader("OSLC-Core-Version", "2.0");

    try {
        // Request the Root Services document
        HttpResponse rootServicesResponse = HttpUtils.sendGetForSecureDocument(
                                                server, rootServiceDoc, login, password, httpclient,JTS_Server);

        if (rootServicesResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            // Define the XPath evaluation environment
            XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
            xpath.setNamespaceContext(
                    new NamespaceContextMap(new String[]
                            {   "rdf", "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
                                "oslc_we","http://open-services.net/xmlns/we/1.0/"}));

            // Parse the response body to retrieve the catalog URI
            InputSource source = new InputSource(rootServicesResponse.getEntity().getContent());
            Node attribute = (Node) (xpath.evaluate(catalogXPath, source, XPathConstants.NODE));
            String serviceProvidersCatalog = attribute.getTextContent();
            rootServicesResponse.getEntity().consumeContent();

            // Setup the catalog request
            HttpGet catalogDoc = new HttpGet(serviceProvidersCatalog);
            catalogDoc.addHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
            catalogDoc.addHeader("OSLC-Core-Version", "2.0");

            // Access to the Service Providers catalog
            HttpResponse catalogResponse = HttpUtils.sendGetForSecureDocument(
                                                        server, catalogDoc, login, password, httpclient,JTS_Server);
            if (catalogResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                // Define the XPath evaluation environment
                XPath xpath2 = factory.newXPath();
                xpath2.setNamespaceContext(
                        new NamespaceContextMap(new String[]
                                {   "oslc", "http://open-services.net/ns/core#",
                                    "dcterms","http://purl.org/dc/terms/"}));

                // Parse the response body to retrieve the Service Provider
                source = new InputSource(catalogResponse.getEntity().getContent());
                NodeList titleNodes = (NodeList) (xpath2.evaluate(serviceProviderTitleXPath, source, XPathConstants.NODESET));

                // Print out the title of each Service Provider
                int length = titleNodes.getLength();
                System.out.println(">> Project Areas:");
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(">> \t - "+ titleNodes.item(i).getTextContent());
                }
            }
        }
        rootServicesResponse.getEntity().consumeContent();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidCredentialsException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Shutdown the HTTP connection
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Not an answer, but see if the following will give you any hints (see the answer to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392206/programmatically-modify-credential-in-worklight-adapter)

Comment: Is login a static method? Could you please post loginToRM.java?

Comment: Please also check if there is a field whose name is "login".

Comment: And also check your eclipse's compiler version and server's Java version to make sure they compatible. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=449264

Comment: i have compiled and runned the same java code separately in eclipse  and then i was able to login to my server

Answer (score 3):

I just figured this out. It's funny how everyone went silent on this issue for two months. For me it wasn't obvious at all because it works in some projects and simply doesn't in others. The same is true for machines. It'll work one place, but not another (if you're not aware of what's going on).

Check your .project file and make sure it has the right buildCommand tags in it.

```
<buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.javascriptValidator</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>com.worklight.studio.plugin.WorklightProjectBuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
```

Read more at: [ECMA TypeError calling Java class from Worklight adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614742/ecma-typeerror-calling-java-class-from-worklight-adapter/16761874#16761874)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that login() function is public and static. Check out a sample code of the training module you're working with.

Comment: i have posted my login function above and it is static and also public